# How to show time in minute:second format, with minutes including the hours?

Tags: android, datetime, time, chronometer

I want to show the time elapsed from a certain point in my view. I am using the `Chronometer` class for that.

The issue is, however, that after one hour, it goes to show "1:00:00", but I want it to show 60:00 and so on (like after 80 minutes it should be 80:00 and not 1:20:00)

I have tried using `SimpleDateFormat` class with "mm:ss" formatting. Sure, it doesn't show the hour, but after an hour it just goes to 00:00 and so on.

Is there a solution for this, such as a custom formatter in Java that I can use?

Comment: Why don't you try your own custom formatting if you just want to show a String?

Comment: @Kunu I tried but it kept showing unexpected strings. That's when I decided to ask for the wisdom the people of StackOverflow have to offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the solution I came up with after combining @[parliament's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3127838/parliament) answer:

```
// This is my base time for the chronometer
baseTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - (new Date().getTime() - myInitialTimeInMillis);
Date baseDate = new Date(baseTime);
chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(chronometer1 -> {
        baseTime += 1000;
        baseDate.setTime(baseTime);
        chronometer.setText(getTimeInMinuteSecondFormat(baseDate));
});
chronometer.start();
```

This is my common util method for getting formatted time:

```
public static String getTimeInMinuteSecondFormat(Date date) {
    String displayTime = getHourMinuteSecondFormatDate(date);
    String[] splitDisplayTime = displayTime.split(":");
    if (Integer.valueOf(splitDisplayTime[0]) <= 0) {
        return splitDisplayTime[1] + ":" + splitDisplayTime[2];
    } else {
        return (Integer.valueOf(splitDisplayTime[0]) * 60) + Integer.valueOf(splitDisplayTime[1]) + ":" + splitDisplayTime[2];
    }
}
```

Works like a charm! Thanks @[parliament](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3127838/parliament)

Answer (score 2):

```
String displayedTime = your time in format of HH:mm
String[] splittedTime = displayedTime.split(":");
String desiredTimeFormat = String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(splittedTime[0])*60) + ":" + splittedTime[1];
```

Comment: So easy and hackish answer. I like it xD

Comment: Indeed, thanks for this idea, I'll try to customize this to my requirements and post the answer